# Symmetric algebra of a fiber product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and consider the pull-back diagram
$$
M\times_L N \rightarrow M
$$
$$
\hspace{5mm} \downarrow \hspace{15mm} \downarrow f
$$
$$
\hspace{3mm} N \hspace{5mm} \xrightarrow{g} \hspace{3mm} L
$$
of finitely generated $R$-modules. Taking symmetric algebras yields
$$
\operatorname{Sym}\left(M\times_L N\right) \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(M)
$$
$$
\hspace{10mm} \downarrow \hspace{30mm} \downarrow \operatorname{Sym}(f)
$$
$$
\hspace{3mm} \operatorname{Sym}(N) \hspace{5mm} \xrightarrow{\operatorname{Sym}(g)} \hspace{3mm} \operatorname{Sym}(L)
$$
which we can not in general expect to be a pull-back diagram.

My question is:
When does it become a pull-back diagram?

(e.g. $R$ is a field, or $M$, $N$, $L$ are all free, or $f$, $g$ are injective, or $(f \ \ g)$ is surjective, etc.)

Is there a nice description between the symmetric algebra of a pull-back and the pull-back of symmetric algebras?

I tried with some examples where it became a pull-back diagram as follows:
$$
\mathbb{k}\left<\beta\right> \rightarrow \mathbb{k}\left<\alpha,\beta\right>
$$
$$
\hspace{1mm} \downarrow \hspace{20mm} \downarrow
$$
$$
\hspace{3mm} \mathbb{k}\left<\beta,\gamma\right> \hspace{2mm} \rightarrow \hspace{3mm} \mathbb{k}\left<\alpha,\beta,\gamma\right>
$$
is a pull-back diagram of $\mathbb{k}$-vector spaces and after taking symmetric algebras it becomes another pull-back diagram
$$
\mathbb{k}\left[\beta\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{k}\left[\alpha,\beta\right]
$$
$$
\hspace{1mm} \downarrow \hspace{20mm} \downarrow
$$
$$
\hspace{3mm} \mathbb{k}\left[\beta,\gamma\right] \hspace{2mm} \rightarrow \hspace{3mm} \mathbb{k}\left[\alpha,\beta,\gamma\right]
$$
but I failed to find a nice assumption in general.
It would be helpful for me to hear any comments. Thank you.

Comment: There will be counterexample because of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810475 and since a functor preserving pullbacks also preserves monomorphisms. In fact, $A \to B$ is a monomorphism iff the square with sides $A \to A \to B$ and $A \to A \to B$ is a pullback.