# Symmetric algebra functor preserves injectivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The symmetric algebra functor $\operatorname{Sym}$ is defined from the category of $R$-modules to the category of (graded) commutative $R$-algebras.
It takes an $R$-module homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ to an $R$-algebra homomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}(f):\operatorname{Sym}(M)\rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(N)$.
Because $\operatorname{Sym}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor,
it is right exact.
Therefore, if $f$ is surjective, $\operatorname{Sym}(f)$ is also surjective.

My question is that if $f$ is injective, $\operatorname{Sym}(f)$ is also injective?

First I thought that it is false but I couldn't find any counterexamples.
Is it true if $R$ is sufficiently good (e.g. field, integral domain, etc.) or $M$, $N$ are particularly nice (e.g. free, projective, ...) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "right exact"? The category of $R$-algebras is not abelian.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov By definition, a functor is right exact when it preserves finite colimits. This works for all categories. Any right exact functor preserves epimorphisms.

Comment: Actually, the argument for preservation of surjective maps is therefore not correct, since epimorphisms of algebras don't have to be surjective. Anyway, of course $\mathrm{Sym}(-)$ preserves surjections.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use that surjective maps of modules / algebras are precisely the *regular* epimorphisms, and right exact functors preserve regular epimorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, consider the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\stackrel{2}\to\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  If $x$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, then $x^2\neq 0$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}/(2))$, but the induced map $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}/(2))\to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z}/(4))$ sends $x^2$ to $4$ times a generator of $\operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb{Z}/(4))$, which is $0$.

(For a more dramatic example of the same idea, you could take the inclusion of any nontrivial cyclic subgroup into $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=0$ so all of its symmetric powers above the first are trivial.)

It is true over a field, since over a field any injective homomorphism has a left inverse and so will still have a left inverse after applying Sym.

Comment: +1. What do you suspect for the case of free modules (when the ring is not an integral domain)? I wrote an answer, but then needed to delete it because of unfixable errors.

Comment: I would guess there are counterexamples but I don't have much confidence in that guess.

Comment: Suppose $M$ and $N$ are free, with bases $x_i$ and $y_j$ respectively. Then $\mathrm{Sym}(M)$ is the polynomial ring $R[x_i]$, with the degree $d$ part being $M^{\otimes d}=M\otimes_RM\otimes\cdots\otimes M$. Similarly for $\mathrm{Sym}(N)=R[y_j]$. Now a map $f:M\to N$ yields in degree two the map $f\otimes f:M\otimes M\to N\otimes N$, which we can factorise as $(f\otimes 1)(1\otimes f): M\otimes M\to M\otimes N\to N\otimes N$. If $f$ is injective, then flatness of free modules tells us that both $f\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes f$ are injective.

Comment: Induction shows that $f^{\otimes d}$ is injective for all $d$, so $\mathrm{Sym}(f)$ is injective. In fact, we see that this holds for injective maps between flat modules.

Comment: @AndrewHubery This is not correct, your proof only works with the tensor algebra. The part of $\mathrm{Sym}(M)$ in degree $d$ is $\mathrm{Sym}_d(M)$, the quotient (!) of $M^{\otimes d}$ modulo $\otimes_i m_i = \otimes_i m_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: Yes, or course.

Answer (score 1):

#### Free modules

I think it should be true when $M,N$ are free. My proof is not complete yet, but here is some progress.

By using standard arguments with filtered colimits, we can easily deduce to the finite case. Then the question is just: If $f : R^m \to R^n$ is an injective linear map, represented by a matrix $(a_{ij}) \in R^{n \times m}$, is the induced algebra homomorphism
$$\mathrm{Sym}(f) : R[T_1,\dotsc,T_m] \to R[T_1,\dotsc,T_n], ~ T_j \mapsto \sum_i a_{ij} T_i$$
also injective? This is a homomorphism of graded algebras, so it suffices to look at homogeneous polynomials of a given degree. The degrees $0$ and $1$ are easy.

If $R$ is a field, it is of course true (see also Eric's answer). It then follows also when $R$ is an integral domain.

Let us consider the special case $m=1$, so $f$ corresponds to an element $(a_1,\dotsc,a_n) \in R^n$ with $\mathrm{Ann}(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)=0$, and $\mathrm{Sym}(f)$ maps $T_1 \mapsto \sum_i a_i T_i$. Here is a proof that $\mathrm{Sym}(f)$ is, in fact, injective:

Take an element $r T_1^d$ in the kernel (as said earlier, it suffices to consider homogeneous elements). By the multinomial theorem, this means
$$0 = r \sum_{i_1+\cdots + i_n=d} \binom{d}{i_1 ~ \cdots ~ i_n} a_1^{i_1} \cdots a_n^{i_n}.$$
for all partitions $i_1+\cdots+i_n=d$. In particular,
$$r \cdot  a_i^d = 0$$
for all indices $i$. Let $s := n \cdot d$. By the pigeonhole principle, for all indices $i_1,\dotsc,i_s$ we deduce
$$r \cdot a_{i_1} \cdots a_{i_s} = 0,$$
since in fact every such product will contain some $a_i$ at least $d$ times. But then, since $\mathrm{Ann}(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)=0$, we deduce
$$r \cdot a_{i_1} \cdots a_{i_{s-1}} = 0$$
for all indices $i_1,\dotsc,i_{s-1}$. We can continue inductively in the same way to reduce the number of factors. In the end, no factors are left, so that $r = 0$ and we are done.

#### Flat modules in characteristic $0$

The result holds when $M,N$ are flat and $R$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra: The natural epimorphism $M^{\otimes d} \to \mathrm{Sym}^d(M)$ splits via $$\omega_M : \mathrm{Sym}^d(M) \to M^{\otimes d},~m_1 \cdots m_d \mapsto \frac{1}{d!} \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_d} m_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdot \otimes m_{\sigma(d)}.$$
If $f : M \to N$ is a linear map, the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} \mathrm{Sym}^d(M) @>{\mathrm{Sym}^d(f)}>> \mathrm{Sym}^d(N) \\ @V{\omega_M}VV @VV{\omega_N}V \\ M^{\otimes d} @>>{f^{\otimes d}}> N^{\otimes d} \end{CD}$$
commutes. If $f$ is injective, since $M$ and $N$ are flat, $f^{\otimes d}$ is injective. Since $\omega_M$ is injective (even a split monomorphism), we see that $\mathrm{Sym}^d(f)$ is injective .

So if $R$ is arbitrary (but $M,N$ are still flat), use the localization functor $M \mapsto M_{\mathbb{Q}}$ to deduce that $\mathrm{Sym}^d(f)_{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathrm{Sym}^d(f_{\mathbb{Q}})$ is injective. This means that any element in the kernel of $\mathrm{Sym}^d(f)$ is killed by some non-zero integer (in fact, by $d!$). Since in our proof above we see nothing about these integers, I highly suspect that $\mathrm{Sym}^d(f)$ is injective, but I haven't finished the proof.